# PIC : problem with initialize internal RTC of PIC18F67k22

Tags: pic, rtc

I want to initialize the internal RTC of a [PIC18F67K22](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC18F67K22) with some fix time and date. Time is set properly, but date is not set properly. The problem occurs in setting the year. **year** is not set to whatever we give to RTC.

Find attach below RTC code, which I write to initialize internal RTC.

```
 RtccInitClock();                                       //Intialize the internal RTC
 RtccWrOn();                                                //Write enable for RTC                              //enable RTCC output on RTCC output pin
 PIE3bits.RTCCIE=1;                                     //Enables the alarm interrupt from RTC

       RtccTimeDate.f.hour = 2;                             //Set Hour
       RtccTimeDate.f.min =  3;                             //Set minute
       RtccTimeDate.f.sec =  4;                             //Set second
       RtccTimeDate.f.mday = 05;                            //Set day
       RtccTimeDate.f.mon =  06;                            //Se month
       RtccTimeDate.f.year = 14;                            //set year

      RtccWriteTimeDate(&RtccTimeDate,1);                       //Writes the date and time read from the external RTC
      delay_ms(10);
      RtccSetAlarmRpt(RTCC_RPT_SEC,1);                      //Set the alarm repeat to every minute
      ALRMCFGbits.CHIME = 1;                                    //Alarm repeat infinite times
      RtccWriteAlrmTimeDate(&RtccTimeDate);                     //Writes Alarm date and Time
      mRtccOn();                                                //Enables the RTC
      mRtccAlrmEnable();
```

Is there any setting I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [some RTCC documentation](http://bravo.univ-tln.fr/er/Robots/2011%202012/Periago%20Projet%20Vierzon%202012/Documentation/docs/periph_lib/dsPIC33F_PIC24H_dsPIC33E_PIC24E_RTCC_Library_Help.htm) that I found for that library both the date and time values should be specified in [binary-coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). Read up on BCD encoding so that you understand how it works but for the moment to confirm that's the problem try the following code:

```
RtccTimeDate.f.hour = 0x02;
RtccTimeDate.f.min =  0x03;
RtccTimeDate.f.sec =  0x04;
RtccTimeDate.f.mday = 0x05;
RtccTimeDate.f.mon =  0x06;
RtccTimeDate.f.year = 0x14;
```

While I have changed all the values for clarity it's only the year that actually changes for your example value. The value 14 in decimal is 0x0E in hex which isn't a valid BCD value. You could use something like the following (untested) macro to covert to BCD:

```
#define TO_BCD(x) ((((x) / 10) << 4) + ((x) % 10))
RtccTimeDate.f.year = TO_BCD(14);
```

Comment: Thanks peter J. You are right. RTC accept hex value and year is convert to BCD form .